# Why do we subtract the value of the anti-derivative at the lower bound from the upper bound?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am new to calculus. I have understood the concept of derivatives very nicely and am really confident regarding the topic. 
 But when it comes to integrals, I get confused. I understand that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ refers to the area under the curve $f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$, and that we can find a function $F(x)$(the indefinite integral of $f(x)$) which gives the values of the areas under the curve of the function $f(x)$ & that it is the anti-derivative of $f(x)$. But what I dont understand is that why do we have to subtract its value from the upper bound and the lower bound. That is, when we take the definite integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, why is it equal to $F(b)-F(a)$? In-depth answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you know and understand integration as a limit of sum then combine that with Lagrange's mean value theorem. Those two things should be enough to prove and to understand this result. In case you don't know, it is called fundamental theorem of calculus. You can look up for proofs on internet. You will probably find different proofs that give different insight.

Answer (score 3):

It might help to think of an "accumulation function." If you have a function $f(x)$ define a new function

$$F(x) =\int_0^x f(t) \; dt.$$

The value of $F(x)$ is the area under the curve between $0$ and $x$.  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that $F'(x) = f(x)$ so $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$.  (I chose $0$ for the lower limit just for convenience.  You can pick about any constant you want, as long as the integral is defined and convergent.)

So what's the area under the curve between $x=2$ and $x=5$.  On one hand we'd write

$$\int_2^5 f(x) \; dx.$$

On the other hand, it would be the area from $0$ to $5$ minus the area from $0$ to $2$, which is

$$F(5)-F(2).$$

So it's a subtraction of areas.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this question that I find helpful is understanding the derivative as a measurement of "How much a function changes", which works since a positive derivative says to you "This function is growing" and a negative that "It's decreasing".

With this framework, we can ask "What does $\int_a^b f'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ represent". Well, from the Riemman sum definition of the integral we know that the integral can be seen as a sum of  $f'(x) \Delta x$ where $\Delta x$ is a small change in the $x$ axis. But since the derivative measures how much a function changes, then $f'(x) \Delta x$ is just "How much the function increases on the small step $\Delta x$":

> $\int_a^b f'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ is the sum of how much $f$ *changes on each small step* $\Delta x$ from $a$ to $b$

On the other hand, $f(b) - f(a)$ gives you the *total change* of the function from $a$ to $b$. It literally measures how much $f$ increased or decreased from $a$ to $b$:

> $f(b) - f(a)$ gives you the *total change* of the function from $a$ to $b$

Now imagine that $f$ models the height of a building, like the Eiffel
Tower. In this case, we can now use this nice quote from professor David J. Griffiths to bring it all together:

> Suppose you wanted to determine the height of the Eiffel
> Tower. You could climb the stairs, using a ruler to measure the rise at each step, and adding
> them all up, or you could place altimeters at the top and
> the bottom, and subtract the two readings; you should get the same
> answer either way.

The "measuring each step" approach is exactly the "sum of how much $f$ *changes on each small step*" we gave, whilst the altimeter approach is the "total change" approach mentioned afterward. And since you get the same answer either way, both approaches must be equal, thus
$$
\int_a^b f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(b) - f(a)
$$

---

All the above should be taken only as intuition for why the Fundamental theorem of calculus is true. I played fast and loose with the details, but when you're dealing with "small changes" you need to be very careful or you can end up with incoherent results. For a formal explanation as to why this holds you should read a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus such as
[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1261464/695196).